# How can I optimize this query?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, select, join

How can I optimize this query? It seems there should be a much easier way to do this. The goal is that it will still be able to be readily turned into a delete statement.

```
SELECT * FROM team 
WHERE team_id IN (
                  SELECT team_id 
                  FROM (
                        SELECT team.team_id, (
                                              SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                              FROM signup 
                                              WHERE signup.team_id = team.team_id
                                             ) AS members 
                        FROM team, schedule, event 
                        WHERE team.schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id 
                        AND schedule.event_id = event.event_id
                        AND event.event_id =183) AS t 
                  WHERE members = 0
                 )
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the data and what the query should do/return?

Comment: And how about you format that code a little better...

Comment: I formatted the code for you. It's very helpful to write all SQL stuff in capital letters and your tables, columns and aliases small. Then it's also a good idea to indent your code. This way you can actually see, what the query is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick glance at this query gives me this:

```
select
    t.*
from
    team t
    inner join schedule s on t.schedule_id = s.schedule_id
    inner join event e on s.event_id = e.event_id
    left outer join signup sp on t.team_id = sp.team_id
where
    e.event_id = 183
    and sp.team_id is null
```

It looked like you're trying to find all teams that are in an event but are not in the signup table.  Is this accurate?

Also, I wanted to note that it will be faster to do joins then a bunch of subqueries, especially if the subqueries depend on each row (in your case, they do).

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted. I am still working on being able to use different types of joins well. 

(I should note that on the second inner join in you query it was actually s.event_id = e.event_id, not schedule_id)

Comment: Fixed it, and glad it helped!

Comment: now that you have better SQL, make sure you check the query plan for the query. if you want to complete the optimization then you'll want to ensure it is fast as well. If the tables are large (or will eventually grow large) and you don't have the right indexes then your query will run slow. If you add indexes and then your writes become slow then post another question and we'll answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting on Eric's query in this thread, I would recommend (from my mssqlserver background) to use an existential check instead. Doing so (1) makes your intent more clear and (2) gives the optimizer the opportunity to stop examining for a matching team_id after  the first one is found (since >=1 matching row causes the existential check to be false).
E.g.

select
    t.*
from
    team t
    inner join schedule s on t.schedule_id = s.schedule_id
    inner join event e on s.event_id = e.event_id
where
    e.event_id = 183
    and not exists (select * from signup where team_id = t.team_id)

But maybe there are mysql specific perf concerns.